# Issue with Arrays/Match/Index

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

Here is my current formula I use to pull the latest live date for a customer out of a web query.

```
{=LARGE(
    IF(Table_owssvr_1[HQ Name]=B1,1,0)*
    IF(ISNUMBER(Table_owssvr_1[Live Date]),Table_owssvr_1[Live Date],0),
  1)}
```

`B1` is the name of the customer.  `HQ name` is column `A` and contains customer names.

This formula will give me the latest open date for the customer but it doesn't filter whether it was a live, closed, or customer on hold.  The problem I am having is that I need to have this formula check one more column in that table to see that is matches `Live -3` before giving me the largest date.  It is column `C` in the table `Status`.  If the data in the column says `Live -3` for that customer, then I need it to pull the largest date from among multiple entries that say the `Live -3`.  The dates are in column `L`, `Live Date`.

I've been attempting using match and index function but have had no luck.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried adding another condition like the first `IF(Table_owssvr_1[Status]="Live -3",1,0)` and multiplying it by the rest of the conditions?

Comment: Yep, that was my first attempt.  I could only get it to return 1 therefore it didn't limit the choices at all.

Comment: So `LARGE(
        IF(Table_owssvr_1[HQ Name]=B1,1,0)*
        IF(Table_owssvr_1[Status]="Live -3",1,0)*
        IF(ISNUMBER(Table_owssvr_1[Live Date]),Table_owssvr_1[Live Date],0),
      1)` doesn't work?  If so, can you do a separate test that some of the cells in `Status` actually equal `"Live -3"`? It's possible your test string does not match the actual values (trailing spaces, etc.).

Comment: I copied and pasted your formula and it worked.  I thought I was doing something very similar... must have just been missing 1 thing.  I appreciate your help Byron. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as multiplying in another condition that returns `1/0`.  You will get a 0 unless both conditions are met.

```
{=LARGE(
    IF(Table_owssvr_1[HQ Name]=B1,1,0)*
    IF(Table_owssvr_1[Status]="Live -3",1,0)*
    IF(ISNUMBER(Table_owssvr_1[Live Date]),Table_owssvr_1[Live Date],0),
  1)}
```